# A day's hard work or hard day's work

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Most people like to rest after a day's hard work but he seemed to have an inexhaustive supply of energy.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct ? Is the phrase *day's hard work* correct or is it *hard day's work* ?

Comment: This is a matter of choice, not grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Both options are grammatically correct. However, you should probably use a ***hard day's work*** instead of a ***day's hard work.***

A ***hard day's work*** is a set phrase, even though "hard" is modifying "day." A ***day's hard work*** is actually more logical -- "hard work" is a very common phrase. However, native English speakers would not usually say a ***day's hard work***. It sounds awkward, because a ***hard day's work*** is much more common -- and to change the order of the words seems like a humorous attempt to misquote the set phrase on purpose.

So I would recommend using ***hard day's work***.

A perfectly good alternative is to say ***a day of hard work.*** Or even ***a long day of back-breaking work***.

Comment: If you are going to use "back-breaking", I would replace "work" and upgrade to "labor"

Comment: Ha, I can go for that!