# "A hard working day" VS "A hard day's work"

Tags: expressions, phrases

I would be appreciative if anyone could help me with choosing the right answer:

> - I had a quite ............ and  I felt so sleepy. I'm off to bed.

a. hard working day 
b. hard day's work

I think "a" can possibly cause some ambiguities while it is close to the adjective "hard-working"; otherwise it is quite natural and idiomatic to me.
As for "b" I have no idea if it is what I need here or not.

P.S. unfortunately [the similar thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/144979/a-days-hard-work-or-hard-days-work) was not that helpful that I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two different things.

A "working day" is an idiomatic way of referring to a day designated for work. For example, in a typical working week, Monday to Friday are 'working days', Saturday and Sunday are not.

A "day's work" means a day's *worth* of work. It is a measurement of work done. It can also be used prospectively, for example, you could estimate that undertaking a particular task would be *[x] number of day's work*.

They aren't really interchangeable because you could have a working day yet not do any work. For example, if I take a Monday off work as leave, Monday is still a 'working day'.

The most idiomatic way of saying that a day at work was difficult would be:

> I had a hard day *at* work.